# Is there a way to find out where a class is used, other than attempting to delete it with Eclipse?

Tags: apex

When I have a class I believe I no longer use, I usually attempt to delete it and see if there is an error. This strikes me as one of those things that just must be wrong...but I don't see another way. Can someone tell me what I must obviously be missing? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure. in eclipse, do a search (Ctrl- H) for the class name. as long as you down loaded, visualforce pages, apex classes, triggers, and sControles that should cover the majority (if not all) cases.

Comment: A similar approach works for VScode.  One note of warning: apex can now be invoked by Process Builder / Flow.  This means that, unless you've pulled all the flows into your IDE project, you may overlook the usage.  When in doubt, create a fresh sandbox and click "delete" on the class.  The org will usually stop you with specific flow messages.

Comment: You can also do this in a SOSL query by using:
FIND {TheClassYouAreLookingFor} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Body, Name)

Answer (score 21):

Developer Console shows *referenced by* in addition to dependencies.

Eg, selecting the `BlobController` class here reveals that `BlobPage` uses it as a controller.

[image: references]

Comment: Does Developer Console show ALL possible references?

Comment: @BradThomas not all component types create these bindings

Comment: Ok. thank you! So how would I be sure that deletion of any class is "safe" in the sense that it should not break anything?

Answer (score 0):

The product "Sonar" will tell you which design element(s) reference other design elements, including Apex classes. But whether the class' methods have run lately is not possible afaik.

One could add a "breadcrumb" custom object, and create a breadcrumb record in each class' constructor method, but even that would only show that the class hasn't been used for a time, not that it is unused altogether. For instance, maybe it would be executed in a scheduled job that runs annually.