# Find where component is used

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there a way to find where is component used? We have a fairly large community and trying to go thru all the pages in Community Builder would be major pain.

I've tried [this trick](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8437/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-where-a-class-is-used-other-than-attempting-to-delet) only to get circular reference (AuraDefinition.Id references AuraDefinition.AuraDefinitionBundleId).

Comment: If you try and delete the AuraDefinitionBundle and there are references to it you get blocked with a "This lightning component bundle is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com". It then includes the name of the referencing bundle. Not hugely useful to find all the references though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do uninstall a package, yes, it will provide you a type Lightning Component bundle reference:

[image]

However, if you proceed with uninstalling:

[image]

You will be provided with further details. Unfortunately, the community pages are not explicitly mentioned, but, there is a link that you can select which will take you to the community page where it is referenced by in the lightning component bundle, allowing you to delete it or un-reference it in your component, for Example:

[image]

Clicking on the hyperlink to the far right will redirect me to the community page where the component is being used or referenced.